# How to append 2 word documents into 1 using the command line (no vba)

Tags: ms-word, cmd

I'm trying to find a simple solution to append 2 MSWord files into one using Windows 7 command line /batch file only (no vba).

I already tried

```
copy /B /Y file1.doc+file2.doc=file3.doc
```

but file3.doc only gets the contents of file1.doc, but not file2.doc.

Copy works just fine with text documents, but is not working for me on MSWord documents.
Any ideas on how I can accomplish that from the command line?

If doing that in a vb script is simple, I might do it in vb and forget about my batch file approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate text files via `copy`, because the files contain just text without additional structural information. That [does not apply to Word documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313153%28v=office.12%29.aspx), though. I'm afraid what you want cannot be done without resorting to VBA.